# How to add key event listener to google docs

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-docs, content-security-policy, keyevent, x-frame-options

I am working on a chrome extension which disables backspace; it doesn't work in google docs.
https://github.com/tuminzee/disable-backspace

> manifest.json

```
    "name": "Disable Backspace",
    "version": "0.1",
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "description": "A chrome extension which disables backspace key",
    "icons": {
      "128" : "icon128.png",
      "48" : "icon48.png",
      "16" : "icon16.png"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
          "matches": [
            "*://*/*"
          ],
          "js": [
              "main.js"
          ]
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "input"
    ]
  }
```

> main.js

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  if(event.which == 8 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.code == "Backspace" ){
      event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

> warning

```
The page delivered both an 'X-Frame-Options' header and a 'Content-Security-Policy' header with a 'frame-ancestors' directive. Although the 'X-Frame-Options' header alone would have blocked embedding, it has been ignored
```

If you have any resources related to this please share.
Thank you in advance.

[screenshot of console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFoU1.png)

Answer (score 0):

> The page delivered both an 'X-Frame-Options' header and a 'Content-Security-Policy' header with a 'frame-ancestors' directive. Although the 'X-Frame-Options' header alone would have blocked embedding, it has been ignored

It's just a warning, javascript isn't blocked.
The `X-Frame-Options` and `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors ...` HTTP headers do the same thing - block embedding into not whitelisted iframes.
But the last one is more flexible, so `X-Frame-Options` [obsoletes](https://csplite.com/csp76/#frame-ancestors) in favor `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors ...` if both are present. Therefore this warning appears. The `contacts.google.com` publishes both headers for browsers backward compatibility.
Since `contacts.google.com` is in charge for these headers, you can do nothing. Just ignore it.

> 

While researching `contacts.google.com` I found that it publishes another CSP header - `Content-Security-Policy: require-trusted-types-for 'script';`:
[image]

Pls check the Network tab in Dev Tool do you observe this HTTP header in response from `contacts.google.com`.

This header forces using [Trusted Types API](https://csplite.com/csp209/#example) to access some XSS DOM vulnerable sinks on `contacts.google.com` page.
As the test shows `addEventListener()` is [not block](http://csplite.com/csp/test311/#test), but maybe Trusted Types block the insertion of the extension script itself.